# where does copied file location of rdp resides in windows

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, file-transfer, copy-paste, clipboard

In general while we copy in local windows the files resides at clipboard and it would be used from clipboard.

Recently while working on rdp the normal copy paste works with ease which puzzled me where does the file actually resides while copying in rdp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shared clipboard in Remote Desktop *synchronizes* both clipboards – when you copy something on one computer, the clipboard on the other end gets the same thing. There's no "in-between" place, just two identical clipboards.

However, when copying files, the clipboard *doesn't* actually contain the files themselves, it only has a list of *file paths*, with special datatypes indicating that ("shell idlist array" among others). When pasting, the program itself opens and reads those files.

Remote Desktop works with this by converting the list to a slightly different datatype, which doesn't have the paths either, but instructions to request the file from MSTSC [on the client] or from RDPCLIP [on the server]. I couldn't find the actual technical details, but the [Remote Desktop Services blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/tags/clipboard/) has a few related posts.

So the original file is where you found it, the copy is where you pasted it, and it doesn't reside anywhere else but that.